# PHP: Starting while statement, yet only displaying a section of it once without repeating for each mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm not sure exactly what to search for to find my exact results. I am trying to create a system that retrieves data from database (no problem, this works). But I want to organize and minimize the amount of code for each section of the page. I am retrieving code via a MySQL query. I then set the `$count = "0"`. Then I start my while statement `$section = mysql_fetch_array($query) {
$count++ ...`

Here is the tricky part: I want to do two `if ($count > 0)` statements.  First, I want to say that IF `$count > 0`, echo table and headers for the table columns.  I don't want this to repeat inside the while statement.  I want this to only appear once. Basically, excluding this from the loop, but still be inside the while statement, because I don't want two while statements if at all possible.

The second `if $count > 0` will then start echoing out each row result.

Not sure If I'm just being dumb and this isn't possible. It's something I've wondered about for a while now.  I hope you understand what I'm looking for and didn't waste your time.

Comment: show some code, what have you done so far?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot paste my code on here.  All I need to know is how to add something to the while statement for the query but exclude it from the loop itself.  Where as if you put  echo $query['id'] it will pull each id until the loop finishes and echo them out.  I want to display something only once inside the while statement.  The whole reason I need to do this is because I need the actual count statement.  I know how to do this as 2 seperate statements, but I'd rather condense it to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     // print headers
     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
           // display row
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do, is alter your query, so that it retrieves the number of returned rows as well, using the included Count() function.

Then, before the while loop starts, you retrive this value from your Resultset and if it is > 0 you print your table headers and enter the loop.

Hope this helps.